# Sleep time syntax for db2 store procedure

Tags: syntax, db2, sleep, stored-functions

For oracle we can use the following syntax for sleep

```
DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(sleepTime);
```

For mysql we can use the following syntax for sleep

```
DO SLEEP(sleepTime);
```

For db2 how could I achieve this?.
Following is part of my script.

```
REPEAT
IF rowCount > 0
THEN
```

> DO SLEEP(sleepTime);

```
END IF;
DELETE FROM IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN WHERE TOKEN_STATE IN ('EXPIRED','INACTIVE','REVOKED') OR (TOKEN_STATE='ACTIVE');
GET DIAGNOSTICS rowCount = ROW_COUNT;
UNTIL rowCount=0 END REPEAT;
```

How can we do sleep with db2?.Any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the present time IBM did not supply a DBMS_LOCK module for Db2-for-LUW although that may change in the future or you can implement your own if you have the skills.

But If you are using recent Db2 versions for Linux/Unix/Windows, then you can abuse the [DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0053677.html) procedure. It's not an exact match but may be good enough. The idea is to wait a specified time for an alert(signal) that's never going to be triggered (i.e. you have to ensure the code does not signal the specified alert unless you want to interrupt the wait).

for example, the block below will wait for 5 minutes:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR@
 BEGIN
     DECLARE v_outmessage VARCHAR(32672);
     DECLARE v_outstatus integer default 0;
     DECLARE v_seconds INTEGER default 300;
     CALL dbms_alert.waitone('whatever',v_outmessage ,v_outstatus,v_seconds);
 END@
```

There is also the option to implement a sleep function (as an external UDF or an external stored procedure) and that is described [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/sleep?lang=en) (requires C compiler etc).

Comment: thanks for the quick respose. dbms_alert.waitone worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try the undocumented `call DBMS_ALERT.SLEEP(60)`

Comment: what version of Db2? What is `ibm2`?

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. IBM DB2. I'll have to search the version.